# Attach timestamp to created logfile

Tags: python

I have a shell script from which I am creating some logfile in a directory. And this shell script I am executing in python as below.

```
cmd = "sh xyz.sh"
try:
    subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
except OSError:
    print "Failed to run the script.:
```

I want to attach the timestamp on those created logfile which is getting created by xyz.sh script. For this I want to use below python code.

```
b=time.strftime("%x")
c=time.strftime("%X")
ts=b+"_"+c
```

I want to attach the result of 'ts' variable on created log file. For example : if logfile is name as abc.log and output of ts is : 6/19/2016_10:20:16 then my logfile should renamed as 6/19/2016_10:20:16_abc.log
Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: What has the first code block to do with your question? Can't you just use os.rename()?

Comment: @Dirk My code block starts from cmd only. On usng os.rename() how can rename all files generated in a directory by executing xyz.sh script. Could you please let me know. I am bit to python.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the name of the generated logfile, you can use `os.rename` to rename it. Something along the lines of :

```
import time, os

b = time.strftime("%x")
c = time.strftime("%X")
ts = b + "_" + c

os.rename("abc.log", ts + "_abc.log")
```

If you don't know the name of the logfile, you can find it using `os.listdir(os.getcwd())`, which will give you a list with all the files of the current directory (i.e. the one from where you are running your script).